# Where in the source is the Model Field -> Form Field specified?

Tags: django

ala this page http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/#field-types

Basically, I have a bunch of model field objects, and I want to find the corresponding form field that django uses by default.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's set via the `Field.formfield()` method. The field classes themselves are defined under `django/db/models/fields`.